# Why does my Freeglut App comes up with XQuartz/X11?

Tags: eclipse, macos, x11, glut, freeglut

I wrote a little Glut/OpenGL Application with Eclipse on a Mac. If I compile it with glut lib, the app window opens by itself. If I compile the app with freeglut lib, it opens XQuartz/X11 and starts in a window within XQuartz/X11.

Why does freeglut use XQuartz/X11 and how could I force the app to open a window by itself with freeglut and not in XQuartz/X11?

EDIT: I don't like XQuartz because it seems to cut the FPS of my app to 60 FPS. With glut and without XQuartz/freeglut it runs with up to 700 FPS. (Very simple animation)

Some more information:

```
echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-2NP9t5/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Does this environment variable influence the choice of freeglut to use XQuartz? If yes, how could I change it to which value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to GLFW 3 framework. Seems to be the best (more modern) alternative framework than glut/freeglut. Now all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `glut/freeglut`, and I can build with `Cocoa` instead `x11`. Here is my build command:

```bash
cc -o main main.cpp -lglew -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework glut
```